# Configure FOS Elastica for Symfony 3

Tags: php, elasticsearch, symfony

I'm trying to implement FOS Elastica bundle to my project on SF3.
I wrote my config file according to the documentation, so I have such lines there as:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
```

However when I try to make

```
$ php bin/console fos:elastica:populate
```

I have got an exception -  **[Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException]
  Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?**

I tried to add port in Apache by command Listen 9200. After that Elastica make populating correctly but basic search with these 2 lines:

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.store_bundle.product_description');
$results = $finder->find('example.net');
```

returns 0 results.

As I understand I have some problems while configure Elastica server but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: Hello is all your configuration in one server or on your local computer?

Comment: Do you use vagrant, docker, etc?

Comment: I have install Java and run Elasticsearch server but it is interesting for me does I need to do this steps? I mean, how I will use Symfony with Elastica bundle on remote server without installed Java?Or I need to contact with hoster and install java and elastic server?

Comment: FOSElasticaBundle provide integration of Elastica library. It does not provide Elasticsearch. You have to have an Elasticsearch Cluster and there is at least an ip address for this cluster. If you want to use Elasticsearch you should install jvm because Elasticsearch work on it.

Comment: So, as I understand you correctly, I need to install Java (JDK or JVM) on my production server (which is located on a third-party host) and than install Elasticsearech server (such steps I have done on my localhost). And after that I will be able to use FOS/Elastica on my production server?

Comment: Yes. Thats right. You can use cloud as a service of elasticsearch. Check https://qbox.io/ for this. I really like their web sites. Also there is support and lots of blog post to learn.

Comment: Elasticsearch default port is 9200 and you can directly use this port without doint any configuration on your apache or nginx.If you want to forward your port, you can use nginx or apache. Also, you can change your default port on your configuration.

Comment: @hkulekci OK, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have written an article on it you can follow it :) https://www.cloudways.com/blog/elasticsearch-symfony/